# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'Bytes_Written'

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to query a server the code is really simple but I don’t understand why I get this error. I am querying bytes read bytes written and IO operation because I want to later show them in a line chart.

Data

```
{
  "Number of Devices": 2,
  "Block Devices": {
    "bdev0": {
      "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.26.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-d1c8e7c6-8c77-444c-9a93-8b56fa1e37f2-lun-010.0.0.142",
      "Capacity": "2147483648",
      "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
      "IO_Operations": "97069",
      "Bytes_Written": "34410496",
      "Bytes_Read": "363172864"
    },
    "bdev1": {
      "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.26.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-b27110f9-41ba-4bc6-b97c-b5dde23af1f9-lun-010.0.0.146",
      "Capacity": "2147483648",
      "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
      "IO_Operations": "93",
      "Bytes_Written": "0",
      "Bytes_Read": "380928"
    }
  }
}
```

code

```
#Get data checkpoint size
url = 'url'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
print data


def counterVolume(data):
  for each in data:
        x = each.Bytes_Written
        y = each.Bytes_Read
        z = each.IO_Operations
        print {'Bytes_written': x, 'Bytes_Read': y, 'IO_Operations': z}
```

I want the output to be

```
{'Bytes_written': value, 'Bytes_Read': value, 'IO_Operations': value}
```

Comment: because later I want to show them in a line chart using C3.js

Comment: I the part you showed above the output of `print data`?

Comment: That looks like JSON which you need to _parse_. What does `print repr(data)` say?

Comment: I also dont want to give in device ids that is ['bdev0']['bdev0'] because these will keep changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've got a valid JSON response, retrieve your data as such:

```
data = r.json()
```

Then iterate over the block devices:

```
for devname, stats in data['Block Devices'].iteritems():
    print '{} had {Bytes_Read} read and {Bytes_Written} written'.format(devname, **stats)
```

You can print as JSON a subset of the response using:

```
import json

wanted = {'Bytes_Written', 'Bytes_Written', 'IO_Operation'}
for d in data['Block Devices'].itervalues():
    values = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in wanted}
    print json.dumps(values)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this but it does not outputs data according to my desired output which is json

Comment: @lmo well, you're not really outputting JSON - you're outputting the `str`ified version of a Python `dict` which is different... what exactly is the output you want?

Comment: I already updated my question above what I need is something like this {'bytes_read': value, 'bytes_written': value}

Comment: @lmo post updated to show how to print a JSON string contained a subset of the values for each block device in your reesponse

Comment: The above code only produces {"Bytes_Written": "34410496"}
{"Bytes_Written": "0"}, and not the other two values

Comment: @lmo because I typoed the 'IO_Operations' and put 'Bytes_Written' twice...? It's an easy fix to attempt

Comment: I don’t see it where have you written IO_Operations' and Bytes_Written twice?

Comment: @Imo Look at the line that starts with `wanted = ` ?

Comment: ahhh how did i not see that Thank you so much that fixes the problem